# Snowflake SQL output starting from 0 when the offset is set to 2

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

[image: snowflake offset]

On running the below query in Snowflake:

`SELECT seq8() FROM table(generator(rowCount => 5)) limit 3 offset 2;`

why is the output starting from 0 when the offset is set to 2?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this:

```
SELECT seq
from (
    SELECT seq8() as seq 
    FROM table(generator(rowCount => 5)) 
) limit 3 offset 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for 3 random rows, that is what you are getting

LIMIT and OFFSET only having meaning within the context of a ORDER BY

```
SELECT seq8() as s
FROM table(generator(rowCount => 5)) 
order by s
limit 3 offset 2;
```

| S |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |

```
SELECT seq8() as s
FROM table(generator(rowCount => 5)) 
order by s desc
limit 3 offset 2;
```

| S |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 1 |
| 0 |

And given you have expressed an expectation you will see 2, which even with ORDER BY is not "to be expected" behavior, if you need `2` you should use ROW_NUMBER, will all was given exact answers.

```
SELECT row_number() over(order by null)-1 as s
FROM table(generator(rowCount => 5)) 
order by s
limit 3 offset 2;
```

| S |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |